# How to manage string in python

Tags: python

**The problem:**

I want to get trough a file and from this:

```
t - v - m = toyota - volvo - mercedes
```

Get the output:

```
t = toyota
v = volvo 
m = mercedes
```

I've been trying to do that with the `split()` method, but I'm a newbie :)
Thanks!

Comment: Please show your code (how you are using `split()` method), as well as the output/error.

Comment: if you want to use `split`, it takes a delimiter you want to split on:  `lhs, rhs = line.split(' = ')`. `keys = lhs.split(' - ')`, `values = rhs.split(' - ')`. And use `zip(keys, values)` to merge them together for the output (you will get a tuple where the first element is a key and the second element is a value).

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using:

```
t, v, m = "toyota - volvo - mercedes".split(' - ')
```

How it works:

`split(x)` splits a string into a list wherever it finds `x`. So

```
"toyota - volvo - mercedes".split(' - ')
```

Returns:

```
["toyota", "volvo", "mercedes"]
```

Now you can assign this to `t`, `v` and `m` using:

```
t, v, m = ["toyota", "volvo", "mercedes"]
```

Where each variable gets the value of the corresponding item in the list.

Comment: To be more precise i have file with few thousands lines so that kind of split is not working :D

Comment: @joe couldn't you cycle over all the lines? Also, I don't think a couple thousand of lines would be an issue in all honesty

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the input is exactly but since youre referencing a file im asuming a string with that format `t - v - m = toyota - volvo - mercedes` You can create a dictionary like this to do so independent of the amount of data (as long as its in this format)

```py
cars = 't - v - m = toyota - volvo - mercedes'
cars_dict = {}
keys = cars.split(' = ')[0].split(' - ')
values = cars.split(' = ')[1].split(' - ')
for key,value in zip(keys,values):
    cars_dict[key] = value

print(cars_dict)
```